# Unable to Get For Loop to Work in Python Script

Tags: python, for-loop, matplotlib

Good Afternoon,

I am trying to use a for loop to plot graphics via basemap/matplotlib using 10 different data files. Using the code below, it only outputs the plot from the 9th time step/file.

Code:

```
tau = 0

for tau in range(0,10):

  d_num =  "d" + str(tau)
  day = "day" + str(tau)

  date = datetime.now() + timedelta(days=(tau))
  custom_date = date.strftime('%a %d-%b-%y')
  image_date = date.strftime('%Y%m%d')

  homedir='/home/weather/'
  domain='ne'

def mapformat():

  m = Basemap(llcrnrlon=-85,llcrnrlat=36.5,urcrnrlon=-64,urcrnrlat=47,
        projection='lcc',lat_1=33,lat_2=45,lon_0=-70,lon_1=-60, resolution='i')

  m.drawmapboundary(fill_color='aqua', zorder=-1)

  return m

data = np.loadtxt('/home/weather/data/' + d_num + '_tmaxs', delimiter=',', skiprows=1)

m = mapformat()

dx = 0.25

grid_x, grid_y = np.mgrid[-85:-60:dx, 34:50:dx] #Northeast

temp = data[:,0]

grid_z = griddata((data[:,2],data[:,1]), data[:,0], (grid_x,grid_y), method='cubic')

x,y = m(data[:,2], data[:,1]) # flip lat/lon

grid_x,grid_y = m(grid_x,grid_y)

m.contour(grid_x,grid_y,grid_z,clevs2,cmap=custom,linewidths=0.5,zorder=1)

cbar.set_label('Fahrenheit')

plt.savefig(homedir + "/out/abc_tmax_" + d_num + "_ne.png", dpi = 300)

sys.exit()
```

Comment: The end of `range` is exclusive. Do you maybe want `range(11)`?

Comment: Aren't you overwriting the image every time? Or rather not calling savefig as many times as you think - `d_num` is written in the for-loop, but used only once...

Comment: Hi Morgan, I changed range(0, 10) to just range(11) and that plotted timestep 10. I think that vmg is correct about it being overwritten a bunch of times, or it is just skipping to the last timestep (10) and plotting that...

Comment: With range(0,11), you should get 11 iterations, with tau running from 0 to 10.  What are you doing with the extra iteration?  If your numbering starts at 1 instead of 0, then you should use range(1,11).

Comment: Precisely Prune! What's happening however, is that it is running past taus 0-9 and ONLY plotting tau 10, giving me `tmax_d10_ne.png` instead of `tmax_d{0..10}_ne.png`.

Comment: For now, I've gotten this to work by importing a bash variable into the python script and then defining tau as the imported variable in the python script. Python Code: `import sys, tau = int(sys.argv[1])` Bash Code: `padtowidth=1
START=1
END=10
i=${START}

while [ ${i} -le ${END} ]
do

tau=$(printf "%0*d\n" $padtowidth ${i})` And then `tmax_ne.py ${tau}`.

Comment: The underlying issue here is that your plotting code is _outside_ of your loop.